# Multiple webviews in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How can i use three webviews to show multiple html pages say 50 in a scrollview. Any example codes please refer me. My current code is this. it causes memory leak, of course i know it ia a foolish one. I am stuck with this for more than 2 days. please help me.

```
-(void)AddWebviews
{
    [m_CtrlActivity stopAnimating];
    m_CtrlLblProgress.hidden=YES;
    int divisor = WebViewAddCount % 3;
    MagazineAppDelegate     *appdelegate              = (MagazineAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    IstructPageDetails *objPageDetails=[appdelegate.m_mutarrPageDetails objectAtIndex:WebViewAddCount];
    if (divisor==0)
    {
         m_CtrlWebViewone=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768*WebViewAddCount,0,768,1024)];
        // m_CtrlWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
        // m_CtrlWebView.delegate=self;
        NSString *m_strMagazineFolder=[[GlobalFunctions GetCachesFolder]stringByAppendingPathComponent:MAGAZINE_FOLDER_NAME];
        NSString *finalpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@",m_strMagazineFolder,appdelegate.m_StrSelectedMagazineUrl,objPageDetails.m_strFolderName, objPageDetails.m_strPageName ];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalpath isDirectory:NO];

        [m_CtrlWebViewone loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

        m_CtrlWebViewone.scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
        m_CtrlWebViewone.scrollView.bounces=NO;
        m_CtrlWebViewone.scalesPageToFit=YES;
        m_CtrlWebViewone.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


        self.m_CtrlScrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;
        [self.m_CtrlScrollview addSubview:m_CtrlWebViewone];
        [m_CtrlWebViewone release];

    }
    else if(divisor==1)
    {
         m_CtrlWebViewtwo=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768*WebViewAddCount,0,768,1024)];
        // m_CtrlWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
        // m_CtrlWebView.delegate=self;
        NSString *m_strMagazineFolder=[[GlobalFunctions GetCachesFolder]stringByAppendingPathComponent:MAGAZINE_FOLDER_NAME];
        NSString *finalpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@",m_strMagazineFolder,appdelegate.m_StrSelectedMagazineUrl,objPageDetails.m_strFolderName, objPageDetails.m_strPageName ];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalpath isDirectory:NO];

        [m_CtrlWebViewtwo loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

        m_CtrlWebViewtwo.scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
        m_CtrlWebViewtwo.scrollView.bounces=NO;
        m_CtrlWebViewtwo.scalesPageToFit=YES;
        m_CtrlWebViewtwo.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        self.m_CtrlScrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;
        [self.m_CtrlScrollview addSubview:m_CtrlWebViewtwo];
        [m_CtrlWebViewtwo release];
    }
    else if(divisor==2)
    {
         m_CtrlWebViewthree=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768*WebViewAddCount,0,768,1024)];
        // m_CtrlWebView.scrollView.delegate=self;
        // m_CtrlWebView.delegate=self;
        NSString *m_strMagazineFolder=[[GlobalFunctions GetCachesFolder]stringByAppendingPathComponent:MAGAZINE_FOLDER_NAME];
        NSString *finalpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@",m_strMagazineFolder,appdelegate.m_StrSelectedMagazineUrl,objPageDetails.m_strFolderName, objPageDetails.m_strPageName ];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalpath isDirectory:NO];

        [m_CtrlWebViewthree loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

        m_CtrlWebViewthree.scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
        m_CtrlWebViewthree.scrollView.bounces=NO;
        m_CtrlWebViewthree.scalesPageToFit=YES;
        m_CtrlWebViewthree.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        self.m_CtrlScrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;
        [self.m_CtrlScrollview addSubview:m_CtrlWebViewthree];
        [m_CtrlWebViewthree release];
    }

    WebViewAddCount++;


    [self.m_CtrlScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WebViewAddCount*768, 1004)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [UIWebView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple webviews on scrollview at a time is not a great idea,which might lead to memory leak and then app crash.So the best way is to load webview whenever it is necessary.There are two options which i suggest you...

1) Apple has a framework called [UIPageviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef.pdf).There you just need to change the transition type UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl control to UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageSwipe.

2) Use [Bakers framework](https://github.com/germanocaldeira/baker).

Both ARC and Non-ARC codes are available.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: This is not what OP asked :) Question was "Can I" not "Should I". I won't down vote as it is useful info but it doesn't address this question :)